# How to get Exact value of string from a Set using Substring

Tags: apex, string

I have a set of strigs. String is made up of 4 words how can i get the whole string by comparing it with 3 words string..
planProductUniquekeySet contains 100% strings. and 
PlanProductUniqueKey is the 70% string, which i am comparing

```
for(String s:planProductUniquekeySet) {
             if(s.contains(PlanProductUniqueKey)){
                PlanProductUniqueKey=s;
            }
            }
        }
```

Its like i am comparing 70% with 100% of string and i want 100% string value at the end. Above code is giving 70% value at end.

If the string doesn't contain the exact contents of `PlanProductUniqueKey`, I want the entire string returned to me instead.

Comment: Is your criteria that it contain the 3 words and if it does you want the whole string? Your question is somewhat unclear to me. Also, do they need to be in the same order, at one end, or at the start?

Comment: @cromprogdeve Yes I want whole string back..

Comment: Could you answer my other questions? Do you already know the string contains 4 words for example? Does their sequence matter?

Comment: Yes Please, let me give you example, For example... 100% string is abc_def_ghi_jkl.  And my 70 % string is abc_def_ghi...then i want full 100 % value.l

Comment: What you just showed me doesn't contain words. They're both strings since there's no separation or white space.

Comment: Yes its a string

Comment: How are you getting the value for PlanProductUniqueKey. Your code should do what you want based on your comments as long as it is passing the contains. It may not be though depending on how the value of PlanProductUniqueKey is being populated before the compare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as my understanding try this one

```
public class Test_one {
String PlanProductUniqueKey='apple bat cat';
    List<String> planProductUniquekeySet=null;
    public void execute()
    {
        planProductUniquekeySet= new List<String>();
        planProductUniquekeySet.add('dog apple bat cat');        
        planProductUniquekeySet.add('apple bat cat dog');
        for(String s:planProductUniquekeySet) 
        {
            if(s.contains(PlanProductUniqueKey))
            {
                System.debug('--- output---'+s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output is..

```
|DEBUG|--- output---dog apple bat cat
|DEBUG|--- output---apple bat cat dog
```

Comment: Hi, Prade! In this forum, please use "four spaces" to mark code as code (do not use the `<code>` tag). This allows the system to provide proper syntax highlighting and HTML escapes, as needed. You can use the "code" button in the editor to do this for you, or use the shortcut key `Ctrl-K` to add the necessary spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to have a `compare` string and a `test` string. The code you have now compares a string with itself. So, here's the kind of code you would need if you want to know if the `compare` string is contained in the `test` string.

```
string test = // from some source of text values
string compare = 'some string value';
if(test.contains(compare)){

    // you have a match, add your logic here...

}else{

   // no match, add your logic here...

}
```

Comment: There's no need for the `== true` in this code, though.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks for the catch. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex as well.

```
String strTotal = 'abc_def_ghi_jkl';
String strPercent = 'abc_def_ghi';
//Matches abc_def_ghi and anything after
String regExp = '(' + strPercent + '.*)';
String strResult = strTotal.replace(regExp, '');
System.debug(strResult);
```